# What does "shrinking beneath someone's feet" mean?

Tags: phrases, idiom-meaning

I just watched *Batman Rises* on HBO, and I didn't get it when Bruce Wayne spoke about the Cat Woman. He said, "But the ground's shrinking beneath her feet". It seems like it may mean "no one can approach her", but I am not sure.

Comment: If you look at the statements in and around the quote- " We do, so I cross-referenced the address she went back to with police data on high-end B and E's, and um...
[Bruce pulls up a photo of Selina on his monitor]
Bruce Wayne: Selina Kyle. The databases are full of close calls, tips from fences...she's good, but the ground is shrinking beneath her feet."
I'd say it means that the cops are quickly closing in on her, in-spite of her being adept at what she does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a metaphor that means there is less and less room for her to move, as if the ground she is standing on is shrinking. The police/FBI or whoever is investigating her are closing in on her. Eventually she will fall (she will be caught by the authorities).